# How to check if the values lie within the rectangular bound using java

Tags: java

I have a set of values say

```
LatLong1=(lon=74.663085,lat=22.67578)
LatLong2=(lon=80.663085,lat=28.67578)
```

These are the latitude and longitude values of a rectangular bounded region. LatLong1 is the left and bottom boundary values and LatLong2 is the right and top boundary values.

Now I need to check if some object lies within this boundary at current time.
If I have the object's position with 75.67 and 26.89 as latitude longitude respectively. How do I check whether these values lies within the above mentioned LatLong1 , LatLong2 values?

Comment: More information needed! How are those objects that you want to check if they are fully contained? Do we have to assume they are rectangles as well?

Comment: Consider it as a point sir.

Comment: Why have you tagged OpenLayers as a matter of interest. What does a client-side Javascript library have to do with Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've to guess your objects for which pertenency you need to check is a rentangle too, with values:

```
LatLong1=(lon=x0,lat=y0)
LatLong2=(lon=x1,lat=y1)
```

If this is the case, and both graphical structures are tied to the same origin of coordenates, the conditions to check is:

```
if( (x0>=lon0 && x1<=lon1 ) && (y0>=lat0 && y1<=lat1 ) )
    return true;
else return false;
```

If you need to check if a point is inside a rectangle, being the coordinates of the point (x0,y0):

```
if( (x0>=lon0 && x0<=lon1 ) && (y0>=lat0 && y0<=lat1 ) )
    return true;
else return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know openlayer. But isn't it like finding whether a point (x,y) is in a rectangle whose lower left is (x1,y1) and top right is (x2, y2)?

In that case (x,y) is in the rectangle, if `(x>x1 && x<x2 && y>y1 && y<y2)`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a rectangle. With your two points you can compute the upper left corner and the dimension.

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(upperLeftCorner, dimension);
```

You want to check if a point (x,y)  lies in the rectangle:

```
Point p = new Point(x,y);
rect.contains(p);
```